# Why ajax is not working properly with insert to databse

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am going to make a form that calls an ajax after submit. Then I will do two things by ajax: First, I will display the information entered by the user in a table at the bottom of the same page. Second, the information is stored in the database.
But only the second operation (data storage in the database) is performed and the second operation is not performed.

this is my html

```
 <div class="container mt-5 w-50 p-5 bg-warning-subtle">
        <form id="form1">
            <label for="username" class="form-label">username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            <label for="password" class="form-label">password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning px-5 mt-4 fw-bold">go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-5 w-50 p-5 bg-secondary">
        <h1 class="text-primary-emphasis text-center">my table</h1>
        <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-warning" scope="col">#</th>
                    <th class="text-warning" scope="col">First</th>
                    <th class="text-warning" scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th class="text-warning" scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tBody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and this is my js

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form1', function (e) {
        // e.preventDefault();

        const fields = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'sendContactFormData1',
                userData: fields,
                security: baseUrl.nonce
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var i = $("tBody > tr").length + 1;
                $(`<tr>
                <th scope="row">${i}</th>
                <td>${response.username}</td>
                <td>${response.email}</td>
                <td>${response.password}</td>
            </tr>`).appendTo("#tBody");
                i++;
                $("#username").val("")
                $("#email").val("")
                $("#password").val("")
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {

                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and this is my php function

```
function sendContactFormDataCallback()
{
    check_ajax_referer('ajax_nonce', 'security');
    $sendData = [];
    parse_str($_POST['userData'], $sendData);

    $returnData = ["username" => $sendData['username'], "email" => $sendData['email'], "password" => $sendData['password']];

    echo json_encode($returnData);

    global $wpdb;

    $send_to_db = $wpdb->insert("clients", array(
        "userName" => $sendData["username"],
        "email" => $sendData["email"]
    ));
    if ($send_to_db) {
?>
        <script>
            alert("successfully")
        </script>
<?php
    }

    wp_die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendContactFormData1', 'sendContactFormDataCallback');
add_action('wp_ajax_sendContactFormData1', 'sendContactFormDataCallback');
```

I see an interesting thing in the console. js shows me the line of code related to logging the error, while there is no error and everything shows the success of the operation.

my console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D39YP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<script>` tags from the php function to js side ( console.js ) in success function, sending data to js from php is supposed to be the last step before `wp_die()`.

```
function sendContactFormDataCallback()
{
    check_ajax_referer('ajax_nonce', 'security');
    $sendData = [];
    parse_str($_POST['userData'], $sendData);

    $returnData = ["username" => $sendData['username'], "email" => $sendData['email'], "password" => $sendData['password']];

    global $wpdb;

    $send_to_db = $wpdb->insert("clients", array(
        "userName" => $sendData["username"],
        "email" => $sendData["email"]
    ));
    $returnData['send_to_db_result'] = $send_to_db;
    echo json_encode($returnData);
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: thanks your awesome for thinking of me.